# Ignore the empty table and choose value from the non-empty table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a table tab1 and the data is:

```
col1 col2  col3
20  15  2016-04-04 00:00:00.000
25  25  2016-03-03 00:00:00.000
14  14  2016-03-03 22:22:22.223
54  34  2016-04-04 21:22:33.333
```

The other table tab2 is an empty table:

```
col1  col2   col3
```

What I want is that it should always collect values from tab2 and in case, tab2 is empty, it moves to tab1 and collects value from there.

I know I can use COALESCE when the columns are null. But it returns the empty column. This is what I tried (assuming I have a big dataset):

```
select coalesce(tab2.col2, tab1.col2) ab
from tab2, tab1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this:

```
select coalesce(tab2.col2, tab1.col2) ab
from tab2, tab1
```

Isn't the coalesce; it's the join. Or lack of a join, rather.

You'll need to join the tables properly like:

```
select coalesce(tab2.col2, tab1.col2) ab
from tab1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tab2 ON tab1.col1 = tab2.col1
```

Here I joined on `Col1`, so when you `coalesce()` on `col2` it will look for a non-null in `tab2` for a `col1` value, and if it's `NULL` it will grab `col2` value from `tab1` for the same `col1` value.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `ISNULL`. In this case it should function exactly like `COALESCE`.... `ISNULL(tab2.col2, tab1.col2)`. It's a little easier to read, imo.

Comment: Perfect. Never thought about that. Thanks!